# Angular 4: Form model object does not contain the date value when submitted

Tags: angular, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm Currently using bootstrap date picker in the angular 4 project.

**When i select the date from the date picker and submit the form, the date value only does not come in the model object**, it comes as an **Undefined**

I have added my form code and typescript code below, please let me know, what is issue with my code.

```
<form name="details-form" #myform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="getData(myform)" >
    <h4 class="message-heading">Establish new Opportunity</h4>    
    <div class="input-eta">
    <div class="input-label">the ETA?</div>
    <div class="datepicker-box " data-provide="datepicker" data-date-autoclose="true">
       <span class="icons icon-calendar input-group-addon"></span>        
    **<input type="date" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy" name="datepicker" 
                        id="datepicker"  
                        [(ngModel)]="sModel.datepicker" 
                        #datepicker="ngModel" />**
    </div>
    <div class="input-other-details">
    <div class="input-label">Other details</div>
    <textarea placeholder="Type here" name="otherdetails"  [(ngModel)]="sModel.otherdetails"  #otherdetails="ngModel" ></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-row">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-border btn-cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!focusForm.form.valid" class="btn btn-primary btn-submit">Submit</button>          
    </div>
</form>
```

---

```
export class myValueComponent implements OnInit{
**sModel:any = {};**
  constructor(){}

  **getData(modalData){   
    console.log("modalData",modalData.value);
    return false;
  }**

  ngAfterViewInit(){       

  }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the ngx-bootstrap package for all the Bootstrap behavioral (JavaScript) components. Here's a quick link to the datepicker component and how to implement it: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker